# Jenkins shell script not working when in a .sh file

Tags: shell, jenkins

I have a Jenkins job which runs a shell script. It works perfectly when the script is placed directly in the Build command field. But if I put the script in a .sh file and then call that fine from the Build command field:

```
sh $sh_dir/deploy.sh $repo_dir $name $ref $env $site_dir
```

`$sh_dir` is an env variable and the rest are job parameters. It doesn't work, it fails on the first command which is simply

```
cd $1/$2
```

Again, this works perfectly when put directly in the command field, but not when in the .sh file. The output from the .sh file job is:

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/deploy
[deploy] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson6229756058999358596.sh

+ /var/lib/jenkins/scripts/deploy.sh /home/repos magento master live /home/sites
cd: 1: can't cd to /home/repos/magento
```

Yes the directory does exist and yes it is owned by `jenkins`.

I'm going out of my mind trying to figure this out.

Edit: result of deploy.sh with `-x`:

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/deploy
[deploy] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson3304816709711757032.sh
+ sh -x /var/lib/jenkins/scripts/deploy.sh /home/repos magento develop staging /home/sites
+ cd /home/repos/magento
cd: 1: can't cd to /home/repos/magento
```

Comment: Change the `/tmp` script so that it does: `sh -x /var/lib/jenkins/scripts/deploy.sh ...` and then report the output of that.  The `cd: 1: ...` part is odd; normally, I'd expect to see `sh: 1: ...`.  There may be some information in that, but I'm not sure what.  I assume there's no `chroot` stuff going on...you'd probably know if there was.

Comment: Question updated.. I'm so confused

Comment: Hmmm...me too.  The output starts with 'Started by user anonymous'.  Is the problem as simple as 'the permissions on `/home/repos/magento` do not allow user anonymous to `cd` into the directory'?  Maybe add `id` (or `id -a`) to the script before the `cd`, and maybe add `ls -ld / /home /home/repos /home/repos/magento` too.

Comment: User anonymous is a jenkins user, not a ubuntu user.

Comment: OK; then do the `id` and `ls` stuff...

Comment: Even if I hard code ANY directory in the deploy.sh I still get the same "can't cd to ..."

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19896/discussion-between-jonathan-leffler-and-matt-humphrey)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The discussion in the comments was taken to chat.

The problem was eventually discovered to be Windows line endings (CRLF) causing confusion.  For example, the directory `/home/repos/magento\r` with a CR at the end really doesn't exist.  There are Windows CIF shared folders lurking around.  The solution will involve working out how to convert the scripts to native Unix (LF only) line endings.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in jenkins shell script

```
sh 'pwd'
sh 'cd ..'
sh 'pwd'
```

other script

```
sh '''pwd
cd ..
pwd'''
```

In the same "sh" jenkins's cmd, the working directory is same.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue as Matt above but I the Jenkins (anonymous user) did not have permission to change to that folder I was trying to change directory (cd) to. When I switched to /Users/Shared.. folder everything worked fine.